# VS Code wsl gcc build task on all c files that are in a single folder through using *.c is not working

Tags: vscode-tasks

Im trying to create a build task in VS Code that compiles multiple c files in the same folder using the *.c argument in gcc. I believe the problem is that it reads the *.c as a literal string, but I have no clue on how to make it read it as an expression that matches any string.

```
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc *.c",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-std=c99",
                "-pedantic",
                "-Wall",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lm"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

The task terminal will show:

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -g '/mnt/c/Users/user/folder 1/*.c' -o '/mnt/c/Users/user/folder 1/program' -lm <

gcc: error: /mnt/c/Users/user/folder 1/*.c: No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```